# How can I create this table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I want to make a table like the one in the picture. The written code draws the structure of the table but is not the correct delimitation between the rows. I also want to make the table a bigger. How can I do this? My code:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|l}
\cline{3-6}
& & \multicolumn{2}{ c| }{Valori Estimate} \\ \cline{3-6}
& & Clasa & Clasa \\ \cline{1-6}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{\multirow{2}{*}{Valori reale} } &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Clasa} & 3 & 2 \\ \cline{2-6}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Clasa} & 2 & 3   \\ \cline{1-6}
\end{tabular}
```

This is how the table should look:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
\cline{3-4}
  &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Valori Estimate} \\
\cline{3-4} 
  &  & Clasa & Clasa \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Valori reale}} & Clasa & 3 & 2 \\
\cline{2-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}  & Clasa & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: multirow table]

Answer (score 4):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccwc{10mm}wc{10mm}}[hvlines,corners=NW]
                          &       & \Block{1-2}{Valori Estimate} \\
                          &       & Clasa & Clasa \\
\Block{2-1}{Valori reale} & Clasa & 3     & 2 \\
                          & Clasa & 2     & 3 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Hello, François. I didn't know this package, it seems nice ;) But I have errors when compiling: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.5071 \seq_set_map_x:NNn
\c__nicematrix_types_of_matrix_seq \c__nicematrix_...` even with mutiple compilations. Any idea?

Comment: @SebGlav: I think that your LaTeX installation is not up-to-date.

Comment: You might be right, since it doesn't compile even with nothing but the package declaration. Anyway, congrats for this nice feature of yours.

Comment: I thinked that in this question there was @Zarko to create the table, but I have done a mistake. ahahha. :-)